# Como renderizar gráficos em aplicações Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Estou desenvolvendo uma pequena aplicação para ler uma porta serial. Gostaria de saber como faço para gerar um gráfico que seja atualizado em tempo real com duas variáveis, uma x (tempo), e outra y (valor_lido_serial), em C++ com o Qt.

Segue, abaixo, um exemplo do que gostaria de construir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Da uma olhada: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-analogclock.html. Ensina como renderizar gráficos, só que é em inglês.

Comment: Olá Nilton, bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. A sua pergunta está um tanto ampla, pois o QtCreator é um *ambiente de desenvolvimento*. Para evitar que a sua pergunta seja suspensa como ampla demais, eu sugiro que você a edite e defina qual exatamente é o seu problema (não sabe como plotar um gráfico para um conjunto fixo de dados? não sabe como atualizar o gráfico com novos dados? não sabe como fazer com que essa atualização ocorra em intervalos de tempo pré-programados? etc). Além disso, se já tem um exemplo curto de código com um gráfico assim, auxiliaria se colocasse na pergunta.

Comment: Amigo, já tentou ver para utilizar um QTimer?

Comment: Assumindo que já tenha os meios necessários para obter os dados do gráfico, considerou usar o [**`QPainter`**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html) para fazer o desenho? Basta usar a função de desenho de linhas, e a de texto para as legendas.

Comment: Para ser bem direto. Quero algum tutorial, livro ou material que me traga embasamento para construir uma aplicação desse tipo. Conheço a biblioteca QTimer. Irei pesquisar sobre a QPainter.